# Similarity measure for observations with many variable types

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, similarities

I'd like to do some exploratory data analysis using a 2d plot to demonstrate possible clustering of the subjects in a study.

The subjects have many variables recorded, both quantitative and qualitative.

To build such plot of course a similarity measure has to be defined.

Which is the most proper measure for observations with mixed variable type?

(Suggestion on how to plot the diagram with R are welcomed too)

Comment: Down voting should be justified...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several have been proposed.

The simplest (but I wouldn't recommend it) would be to dichotomize all the continuous variables and then use a measure for dichotomous variables.

Somewhat more complex is to first use an appropriate dissimilarity or similarity measure for each variable and then combine those measures, possibly with weighting.

Of the measures that avoid these two work arounds, the most popular is probably Gower's method:

$ s_{ij} = \frac{\sum{w_{ijk}s_{ijk}}}{\sum{w_{ijk}}}$

where $s_{ijk}$ is the similarity for cases i and j on variable k and $w_{ijk}$ is 0 or 1 depending on whether the comparison is valid.

For categorical variables, s = 1 or 0 (1 if there is a match, 0 otherwise) and for continuous variables, Gower suggests

$s_{ij} = 1 - \frac{|x_{ik} - x_{jk}|}{R_k}$

where $R_k$ is the range of k.

(For more details, see Cluster Analysis by Everitt, Landau, Lees and Stahl.)